# Escape character in command of SSIS job step

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, jobs

I have plenty of jobs working on my server. All of them have an SSIS step inside. Recently i've noticed that **msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps.command** column have different patterns in some of jobs. I mean that some of them have escape characters in it, and some dont have. Examples:

1 - with escapes:

> /DTS "\"\MSDB\BlaBla\"" /SERVER SomeServer /CHECKPOINTING OFF /SET
>   "\"\package.variables[Variable_One]\"";"\"VALUE_ONE\"" /SET
>   "\"\package.variables[Variable_Two]\"";VALUE_TWO /SET
>   "\"\package.variables[Variable_Three]\"";"\"VALUE_THREE\"" /REPORTING
>   E

2 - without escapes:

> /DTS "\MSDB\BlaBla" /SERVER SomeServer /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 "
>   /CHECKPOINTING OFF /SET "\package.variables[Variable_One]";"VALUE_ONE"
>   /SET "\package.variables[Variable_Two]";VALUE_TWO /SET
>   "\package.variables[Variable_Three]";VALUE_THREE /REPORTING E

Does anyone can explain to me why some commands are with, and some are without these escape characters?
All of jobs work properly, without problems.

Comment: does the escaping only occur if one of the arguments, like for example the package name itself, contains a space? it would a behavior similar to that of long paths in command prompts then.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, escape characters are needed when the string contains a space. When no space is involved, the escape characters are not required, though they cause no problem either.

Explanation: 
Let's say that value is \MSDB\BlaBla. It can be passed as is, no need for quotes around it.
If value is \MSDB\Bla Bla, in order to pass it requires quotes: "\MSDB\Bla Bla"

The meaning of an escape character (\) is that the exactly next character will be used as a simple character, without special use. In /DTS "... the parser is expecting the next " character to end the string. \" explains to the parser that " character is not the end of the string but a simple character in the string.

So /DTS "\"\MSDB\BlaBla\"" means DTS= "\MSDB\BlaBla"
while /DTS "\MSDB\BlaBla" means DTS= \MSDB\BlaBla

Answer (score 0):

I guess this depends on how the Parameters are passed to the Job.

Following your example, it seems that e.g. one time **"VALUE_THREE"** has been passed and the other time only **VALUE_THREE** (without **""**).

Furthermore it might depend on the way HOW the job / parameters / ... have been added - either programmatically or manually via insert or whatever.

This would explain the different strings in the DB.